# Fastlane: Difference between `build_settings` and `xcargs`?

Tags: xcode, gcc, fastlane

I'm migrating a project to using Fastlane, and I need to pass `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` to xcbuild. I noticed [two arguments](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/xcodebuild.rb#L374-L375) to `gym`, `build_settings` and `xcargs`. What is the difference between these two, and which is the best to use to define these preprocessor definitions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking about *gym*, but the link in your question leads to the code for the *fastlane* `xcodebuild` action, which is a separate thing from *gym*.

To answer your question for *gym*, you should use the `xcargs` option additional arguments for the build phase. For the package phase, use the `export_xcargs` option instead.